# How to hide the icons on the application bar until the ellipsis is tapped

Tags: windows-phone-7

It's easy to have a set of icons always shown, and then when we tap the ellipsis we'll see both the icons and additional menu items. How can we not show anything until we click the ellipsis? The [Dev Center app](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/store/app/dev-center/2d3063c2-4b29-4e69-9c03-50b67b0e6aec) does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these properties:

[MiniSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.applicationbar.minisize%28v=vs.105%29.aspx): Gets the distance that the Application Bar extends into a page when the Mode property is set to Minimized.

[Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.applicationbar.mode%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) Gets or sets the size of the Application Bar.